# If I dereference an illegal address in C I get SIGSEGV with valid gdb backtrace. But if I pass it to snprintf backtrace is trashed

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, x86-64, backtrace

In my x86-64 Linux program I deliberately do:

```
char *ptr = 0x3e8;
int x = *(int *)ptr;
```

When I run it in gdb the process crashes due to SIGSEGV and prints a valid backtrace. If I do instead:

```
char s[16]; 
snprintf(s, 16, "%s\n", ptr);
```

The process still crashes but the backtrace is trash:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5da15c7 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff5c704d3 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

My example may look contrived but my production code is crashing in `snprintf()` in exactly the same way. I've compiled with `-g -O0`.

Comment: Probably snprintf doesn’t set up a stack frame that is recognizable to the debugger, because it was not compiled with -O0.

Comment: Gdb shouldn’t “croak” when the program has a bug—that would make it pretty useless as a debugger.

Comment: Isn't that UB to begin with? This code could end up starting judgement day.

Comment: Yes, but the question is more "Why does `gdb` behave like that in the 2nd case and not the 1st?"

Comment: @TanveerBadar Pet peeve: It's not *wrong* to say undefined behavior can make demons fly out of one's nose or any number of other silly outcomes, but don't forget that such talk is a rhetorical device. It's not reality. It's a good way to teach people not to rely on undefined behavior behaving predictably. It's not a helpful response when someone wants to dig deeper and understand what *actually* happens in the real world. Debugging typically has us work backwards from effect to cause. It's nice to have *some* idea of what causes and effects we might see.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm running on a standard x86 Ubuntu 18.04. I do expect it to crash but why is the bactrace unavailable when the bad access is done by snprintf ? And I have compiled with -O0

Answer (score 2):

> The process still crashes but the backtrace is trash

When I build this test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *ptr = (char *)0x3e8;
  char s[16];
  snprintf(s, 16, "%s\n", ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Using `gcc (Debian 9.3.0-3) 9.3.0` and `GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.30-4) stable release version 2.30.`, with `libc6-dbg` installed, I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:96
96      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:96
#1  0x00007ffff7e48756 in __vfprintf_internal (s=s@entry=0x7fffffffd8b0, format=format@entry=0x555555556004 "%s\n", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffda30, mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=0) at vfprintf-internal.c:1688
#2  0x00007ffff7e5a1f6 in __vsnprintf_internal (string=0x7fffffffdb10 "", maxlen=<optimized out>, format=0x555555556004 "%s\n", args=args@entry=0x7fffffffda30, mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=0) at vsnprintf.c:114
#3  0x00007ffff7e335a2 in __GI___snprintf (s=<optimized out>, maxlen=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>) at snprintf.c:31
#4  0x0000555555555169 in main () at t.c:7
```

I suspect that you'll get similar result from *this test case* on a standard x86 Ubuntu 18.04, in which case you are not telling us the whole story, and an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot to get you the real answer.

Comment: You're right. The larger program in which I noticed this behavior is hostapd that I have modified a lot (linked with a C++ protobuf library etc.). I did the same test with the unmodified hostapd and found that the stack trace is good. So what I'm going to do is remove the parts I've added one at a time and see when the problem started happening